# How to save non-English text in sql server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, hindi, non-english

I am trying to develop one desktop application which takes input in hindi from a textbox and saves it into a sql server database.

The textbox font is set to hindi. When I try inserting the hindi text into SQL Server it throws an error on cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(Invalid operation).

How can I insert hindi text into sql server?

Comment: What is the data type of your column in which text will be stored? Also, what is the exception you are getting?

Comment: And what error are you getting?

Comment: @npinti I am not remember it but it throws error on cmd.ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: The error you are getting is vital in helping us help you solve the problem. Without it we cannot do much. I'd recommend you close the question and ask a new one when you have the stack trace at hand. What vendor and version of the Database you are using will also help.

Answer (score 1):

NVARCHAR datatype is the best possible way to handle multi linguistics.

Please find some of the links below for your reference.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25526/help-in-multi-language-medical-database

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic205432-230-1.aspx

Comment: I need textbox value to be inserted in sql server through IDE not direct sql server query

Comment: What do you mean "through IDE"? The textbox doesn't exist in the IDE, it exists in the running program.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I got solution :)